# How to show difference viewContoller in MDCTabBar - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, material-components, material-components-ios

I am a new iOS programming and now i am using `MaterialComponent` which component named `MDCTabBar` which is similar to `UITabBar` in `UIKit`.

Now i am having doubt which i still cannot figure it out how to handle `viewController` in `MDCTabBar`. My rootViewController which is already inherited `MDCTabBarViewController` which it has `selectedViewController` to handle `viewController` for me.

But in the first viewController i would love to have another `tabBar` to stay stick below `navigationController` that i already implemented but only one thing that i cannot figure it out is that how to handle viewController using `MDCTabBar`

Comment: Were you able to find any solution for this?

Comment: @HardikAmal you will find a useful tutorial in this library https://github.com/CosmicMind/Samples#cards--tabs